# Predefined project setting or script for automation

Tags: scripting, settings

How can I create script or project which can be easily modified when I want to change my object?

For example - i want to create 5 similar animations but with different objects. I don't want to set everything from the beginning every time - just replace the object in the middle and don't be afraid that I will break anything.

Comment: yes it is possible. maybe you really wanna ask "how can i ...?"

Comment: I see, I will just edit the question then

Comment: i would provide a blend file - because it is not clear to me, what "should" break? e.g. Do you have a target to constraint to your camera? is that the reason why it breaks? We have no idea what dependencies you have in your scene. And so it makes less sense to show you some python script if your scene is may a bit complex. Just changing the object is a very easy task - you could just keyframe objects visibility - you don't even need python for that. Or use animation nodes or geonodes - they also can do that.

Comment: @Chris So for example:
I got .blend file with some object and its animation settings. 
I open the project and I want to change the object but keep the animation settings - rotation, location etc. to be the same as previously without manually setting it again